# If $A$ is paranormal then $A$ is normal in dimension finite

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-algebras

Let $A\in\mathcal L(V),\dim V\lt+\infty$.

We know that if $A$ normal then $A$ is paranormal. I need help to prove the following:

If $A$ is paranormal then $A$ is normal in finite-dimension.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For a proof see the references [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paranormal_operator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may prove the statement by mathematical induction on $\dim V$. The base case $\dim V=1$ is trivial, because every linear operator is normal. In the inductive step, the statement follows if $A=0$. Suppose $A\ne0$. By scaling it, we may assume that its operator norm is $1$. Thus $Av=w$ for some unit vectors $v$ and $w$. As $A$ is paranormal,
$$
\|Aw\|=\|A^2v\|\ge\|Av\|^2=\|w\|^2=\|w\|.
$$
As $\|A\|=1$, we must have $\|Aw\|=\|w\|$. Hence $W:=\{w\in AV,\ \|Aw\|=\|w\|\}$ contains at least one nonzero vector.

It follows that $r=\dim\operatorname{span}(W)\ge1$. Let $\{Av_1,Av_2,\ldots,Av_r\}$ be a basis of $\operatorname{span}(W)$ and let $w=\sum_{i=1}^rc_iAv_i$ be an arbitrary **unit** vector in $\operatorname{span}(W)$. Since $A$ is paranormal, we have
$$
\|Aw\|=\left\|A^2\sum_{i=1}^rc_iv_i\right\|\ge\left\|A\sum_{i=1}^rc_iv_i\right\|^2=\|w\|^2=\|w\|.
$$
Again, as $\|A\|=1$, we must have $\|Aw\|=\|w\|$. Hence $W$ is a nontrivial invariant subspace of $A$. If we complete an orthonormal ordered basis of $W$ to an orthonormal ordered basis of $V$, the matrix representation of $A$ will become
$$
\pmatrix{U&Y\\ 0&X}
$$
where $U$ is a nonempty (because $r\ge1$) unitary matrix that represents the restriction of $A$ on $W$. Since $\|A^\ast\|=\|A\|=1$, the norm of every row of $A$ is at most $1$. Therefore $Y=0$. But then $X$ is paranormal and by induction assumption, it is normal. Therefore $A=U\oplus X$ is normal.

Comment: what if $A$ is compact

Comment: @Angelina What do you mean? On a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, every linear operator is compact.

Comment: yes ! (we suppose that we are in $\mathbb{K}$) so every linear operator is compact, and if it is paranormal then it is normal .... (compact + paranormal=normal) ...need for proof please !

Comment: @Angelina I thought you were looking for an elementary proof that is specific to finite-dimensional vector spaces and doesn't rely on the proof for general Banach spaces. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: I'm looking for if an linear operator is compact and paranormal then it is normal, in finite-dimensional vector space (as $\mathbb{K}$) ...please !

Comment: @Angelina Then the condition about compactness is redundant, as every linear operator is compact on a finite-dimensional vector space. You only need to assume paranormal-ness. As shown in the answer, this is enough. And what is $\mathbb K$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107001/discussion-between-angelina-and-user1551).

Comment: $\mathbb{K}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ ...... i need a help to prove every compact, paranormal operator is normal in finite-dimensional vector space ....did you understand.... please and thank you!

Comment: No, I don't. If $A$ is compact and paranormal, then $A$ is paranormal, and my answer shows that if $A$ is paranormal, then $A$ is normal. So, we are done.

Comment: In your answer, where do you use the operator's campacity ?!

Comment: We don't need to assume that $A$ is compact (although $A$ is always compact). Mere paranormal-ness is enough.